# Map Reduce execution in eclipse

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

can anyone please tell how to set the HDFS file path in the arguments tab in eclipse. So that the below code wont give out of index exception.

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use run configurations.
Right click on the program, go to run configurations, use java application.
After choosing right project and right program with main function, you need to go to VM Arguments and pass the arguments.

Comment: Thats write in case of eclispe